# A question about distributions/densities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given two random variables $X,Y$ how to show that $P(X\leq Y+x)=\int F_X(y+x)f_Y(y)dy$? I know that $f_Y(y) = \int f_{XY}(x,y)dx$, but have no idea how to go with the previous equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$P[X\leqslant Y+x]=\iint \mathbf 1_{z\leqslant y+x}\,f_{X,Y}(z,y)\,\mathrm dz\mathrm dy=\int\left(\int\mathbf 1_{z\leqslant y+x}\,f_X(z)\,\mathrm dz\right)f_{Y}(y)\,\mathrm dy$$
What is left to do:

- Identify the missing hypothesis which guarantees the second $=$ sign above.
- Identify the inner parenthesis in the RHS.
- Conclude.

Comment: $X,Y$ are independent. Thank you.